# Is calling a method from the same class faster than calling a method from another class in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

Is it faster to call a method that is written in a class then to call a method from another class? For example, would something like this:

```
public class MainClass
{
   private void Caller()
   {
      Method1();
   }

   public void Method1()
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Would that be faster than something like:

```
public class MainClass
{
   private void Caller()
   {
      HolderClass.Method1();
   }
}

public class HolderClass
{
   public void Method1()
   {
      // do something
   }
}
```

Or are they the same? I might have to call "Method1" millions of time so a small difference could matter.

Comment: just try it out by running both of them some millions of time. Then **measure**.

Comment: You really need to read [Eric Lippert's performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), as this is a textbook question to which all of his concerns apply, especially the "is this the right thing to be worried about" angle. (Spoilers: it's not.)

Comment: The second example wouldn't compile, btw. `Method1` is not static.

Comment: _"I might have to call "Method1" millions of time so a small difference could matter."_ - then let us introduce you to [Benchmarkdotnet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) :) => [Getting started](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/guides/getting-started.html)

Comment: In the second example, either `Method1()` needs to be static or `HolderClass` needs to be replaced with an instance of that class. In both cases, call overhead is vanishingly small compared to any real work replacing `// do something`.

Comment: In order to execute `Method1()` from `HolderClass` you have to create `HolderClass` instance, so it will be slower. If `Method1` is `static` the performance will be the same.

Comment: _"call overhead is vanishingly small compared to any real work replacing // do something"_ <== this. What you are thinking about now is _probably_ premature optimization. 1. Make it. 2. Make it work. 3. Make it work fast. 4. Clean it up. (And 3. is optional ;)  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: the general answer to such questions is *measure it*.
Second: it should not make a difference. In the first case you call

```
this.Method();
```

in the second case

```
holder.Method();
```

So both have to resolve the reference access first. In theory, if you make `Method()` static it should be slightly faster because you then spare that. But this nano-scaled stuff will all be lost in other compiler decisions depending on what code `Method` holds. Which makes us come to third:
If you intend to call that method a million times, if you can remove the method call at all, as function calls have a **function call overhead**. To call functions the compiler has to do a lot of bookkeeping, like holding function contexts, pushing/popping that to a stack frame and so on. Rewrite that function to be called only once and iterate a million times over your elements in that function. Instead of:

```
for <millions> {
    // rule one by one with a million calls
    method();
}
```

do:

```
method() {
    for <millions> {
        // rule them all in one call
    }
}
```

This will give you a real performance boost.

Comment: Note that in managed code we're usually dealing with *two* compilers: the C# (or VB.NET or what have you) compiler that produces IL, and the JIT compiler that translates the IL to machine code. The latter is free to inline and rearrange methods as it sees fit (and it gets smarter at this with every release), so your final conclusion about stack frames and iterations and whatnot can very easily be irrelevant as well, if `method` ends up inlined. When you're down to microbenchmarks like this, measuring always comes first, reasoning a distant second and only after you actually see the difference.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Of course, thats why measure is the first advice. I would write both loop versions, swap them and measure it. So i would know if the compilers(s) did a good job inlining.